# Calling an iframe from js with variable

Tags: javascript, iframe, joomla

I have a joomla module in which I want to present an iframe.  The URL in which the module is presented has a parameter - the ID of an event to be presented.  example  URL?1234.  The module (which can contain both JS & html) needs to extract the eventId  from the URL and then insert it into the   call.  I can get the eventId but can't figure out how to put it into the  call and then make the call.  Here are 2 of my attempts - getting the ID works but completing the call seems to be beyond me.

1. This one gives error 'Cannot set properties of null(setting 'src')"

```
<h3>Event Details</h3>
<p><iframe id="eventFrame" style="border: currentColor; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: block;" src="'+ goTo + '", height="1200"></iframe></p>
<script>
var eventID = window.location.search.substring(1);
alert ('The eventID is  ' + eventID);
var goTo ="https://ooc.whyjustrun.ca/events/view/";
alert ('The goTo value is  ' + goTo);
goTo = goTo + eventID;
alert ('The goTo value is now  ' + goTo);
document.getElementById(eventFrame).src = "goTo" ;
</script>
```

2. This one hangs at the end but there is no error message.

```
<script>
var eventID = window.location.search.substring(1);
alert ('The eventID is  ' + eventID);
var goTo ="https://ooc.whyjustrun.ca/events/view/";
alert ('The goTo value is  ' + goTo);
goTo = goTo + eventID;
alert ('The goTo value is now  ' + goTo);
var instruction ='<p><iframe id="event-frame" style="border: currentColor; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; display: block;" src="'+ goTo + '", height="1200"></iframe></p>';
alert ('The instruction  is now  ' + instruction);
document.designMode = "on";                 
document.execCommand("instruction");  
</script>
```

The page combination can be seen at https://ottawaotest.ca/oocj4/ooc-events then click on one of the events in the list on the left.
The resultant URL does work when entered directly, outside of the iframe. It should be like https://ooc.whyjustrun.ca/events/view/5311

I tried each of the 2 scripts given and some more.